# What Does the "Adaptive" in Adaptive Segues Mean?

Tags: ios

I would like to start with an excerpt from [Segue Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/StoryboardSegue.html): "In iOS, the segues are further divided into segues that adapt to size classes and the older, now deprecated types."

So, adaptive for segues means the same thing as it does for layouts: we can specify a set of segues wherein the segue that is actually used is determined by the size classes that are in effect (the same as we do when we create a set of size class dependent auto layout constraints). Great! However, as far as I have been able to discover, there is no way to actually do that. Can anyone help to clarify this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming.

Comment: @Droppy Can you suggest a way to make it a programming question? Perhaps: How does one go about creating an adaptive segue in iOS?"

Comment: No, I can't, sorry.

Comment: That's not quite a place to ask. It's opinion-based question.

Comment: I think that asking for clarifications on Stack Overflow in situations when vendor's documentation falls short is both appropriate, and on topic. Voting to re-open the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New segues adapt to presentation style, not so much to the size classes (although the two go hand-in-hand).

The idea is to help you build a storyboard that targets both iPhones and iPads, with their different styles of presenting data hierarchies arranged as master-detail.

Building a universal application with old-style segues required your app to see if you are in a split view controller (bigger screen) or in a navigation controller (smaller screen), sending a Push or Replace segue based on a situation. New segues let you send a Show or a Show Detail segue, which sense the view controller kind, and do the right thing for your UI style.